# SOAP:Cannot make call to the remote method.Remote host did not respond

Tags: java, ssl, soap

I am accessing a `https` Webservice through a jar, the service gets created and port also get instantiated but when trying to call the remote method of the Web Service ,it throws the following error.

```
com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.ClientTransportException: HTTP transport error: java.net.ConnectException: A remote host did not respond within the timeout period.
```

Please note that i am overriding the hostnameverifier to verify all host names as the certificate added to the keystore had a different CN from the URL of the Web Service that i am accessing through my jar.

```
javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(
                            new javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier(){

                                public boolean verify(String hostname,
                                        javax.net.ssl.SSLSession sslSession) 
                                {
                                    mylog.setLog("Hostname Verification successfully overriden.");
                                    return true;
                                }
                            });
```

The tool that i am using is CXF .Following is the full stacktrace.

```
com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.ClientTransportException: HTTP transport error: java.net.ConnectException: A remote host did not respond within the timeout period.
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpClientTransport.getOutput(HttpClientTransport.java:133)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.process(HttpTransportPipe.java:154)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.processRequest(HttpTransportPipe.java:95)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.DeferredTransportPipe.processRequest(DeferredTransportPipe.java:117)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:599)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:558)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:543)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:440)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.Stub.process(Stub.java:223)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(SEIStub.java:136)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:110)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:90)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:119)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy25.transferFileService(Unknown Source)
    at com.mywsclient.cxf.transfer.FileTransfer.transferToWebService(FileTransfer.java:183)
    at com.mywsclient.cxf.transfer.FileTransfer.run(FileTransfer.java:236)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:738)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:931)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:738)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: A remote host did not respond within the timeout period.
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:381)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:243)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:230)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:377)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:539)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:488)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:424)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:538)
    at com.ibm.net.ssl.www2.protocol.https.c.<init>(c.java:64)
    at com.ibm.net.ssl.www2.protocol.https.c.a(c.java:65)
    at com.ibm.net.ssl.www2.protocol.https.d.getNewHttpClient(d.java:15)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:978)
    at com.ibm.net.ssl.www2.protocol.https.d.connect(d.java:32)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1043)
    at com.ibm.net.ssl.www2.protocol.https.b.getOutputStream(b.java:79)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpClientTransport.getOutput(HttpClientTransport.java:121)
    ... 19 more
```

Comment: is the remote endpoint correct?

Comment: @Reimeus i have specified the url when i am creating the service object ,and it is downloading the wsdl ,i suppose the same url would be carried forward when calling the remote method.

Comment: @Reimeus got the issue, i was dynamically loading the url from the database, and the endpoint in the wsdl that was downloaded was   had the different endpoint that was not reachable .Overriding the endpoint with the same url that was having the wsdl solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally Resolved the issue, the endpoint that was getting used was different than the url where the wsdl was located.Managed to override the same with the URL that had the wsdl and it worked.(Point to note,i was using a dynamic URL to locate wsdl).Below is the code to set endpoint .

```
BindingProvider bp = (BindingProvider) port;
Map<String, Object>req_context_map=bp.getRequestContext();
bp.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, my_url);
```

Cheers.